# Regex replace ^(.*)\r\n unexpected behavior

Tags: regex, notepad++

I can't figure out why a regex behaves the way it does when replacing. Consider the following list:

```
ABC
CBA
DDD
JKL
```

I want to replace each entry so that I'll get the following result:

```
ABC,CBA,DDD,JKL
```

I use Notepad++ use the following for the match:

```
(.*)\r\n
```

And used this in the replace:

```
($1),
```

This lead to the desired result.

However my initial thought was that I could use this match:

```
^(.*)\r\n
```

BUT: This leads to

```
ABC,CBA
DDD,JKL
```

I just can't figure out why it doesn't work that way and leads to that strange result. What am I missing? **Why is ^(.*)\r\n wrong?**

Comment: Are you using notepad++? If yes which version? I cannot reproduce this behaviour...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad tries to match the regex on the first line. It finds one match and replaces as desired. Your new state is:

```
ABC,CBA 
DDD 
JKL
```

It now looks at the next line which now is `DDD` and executes the replace on there.
It now is:

```
ABC,CBA 
DDD,JKL
```

So the fact that your replace is moving the lines is probably confusing your editor's regex-logic.

If you now execute the same regex-replace again this should lead to your desired result.

Comment: I'll just answer the same.

Comment: is that the notepad will do a line by line match?

Comment: After the first replace, Notepad++ have the text `CBA\r\nDDD\r\njkl` so a search for `^(.*)\r\n` will skip over the `CBA`.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cant just use `\s+` and replace it via `,`.You dont need to capture at all.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/26

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use following regex:

```
[\r\n]+$
```

And replace it with `,`

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex like below. Because there may be a possibility of only `\n` or `\r` plus `\n` characters would be present at the line end.

```
(.*)[\r\n]+
```

REplace the matched strings with `$1,` or `\1,`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jC3uR4/2)